# how to draw polygon on canvas with mouse clicks? Pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, polygons

I need to draw a polygon on my canvas but i have to make it with clicks of mouse. For exemple: click one click two tree and so... max of ten clicks and apper a line to fill all clicked points. Pure JS.

```
function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
    var coordinates = [],
        radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
        index = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
        coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
        angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
    }

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
    for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
        context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
    }

    context.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is add a mousedown event handler. In mousedown, push the mouse coordinates into the coordinates[] array.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

context.lineWidth=2;
context.strokeStyle='blue';

var coordinates = [];
var isDone=false;

$('#done').click(function(){
  isDone=true;
});

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

function handleMouseDown(e){
  if(isDone || coordinates.length>10){return;}

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  coordinates.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  drawPolygon();
}

function drawPolygon(){
  context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for(index=1; index<coordinates.length;index++) {
    context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
  }
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click to assign polygon vertices</h4>
<button id=done>Click when done assigning points</button>
<br><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for support me this works fine! Another question if is possible to select my polygon and drag and drop (draggable)?

Comment: @coreid,  Glad I could help. Drag/drop is indeed a separate question :-)